# Search all subfolders for a foldername that has a specific string

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file that will search all subfolders in a folder, find any folder named `Reports` (there will be many and file paths will be changing constantly) and then copy the reports folders contents (not the folder) back to a root directory for export. For example: I have a folder on my desktop called `Cases`.  I need to search all sub folders for folders called `Reports` and then copy those files out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please specify the OS that you are using. Also, if you could provide code and link that you have already tried, that would be helpful to the coders answering your question.

Comment: Start with a `for /d /r` to get get all folders named Reports (needs a (pseudo)-wildcard) `for /r X:\start\here /d %A in (Reports.?) Do @Echo %~fA` on cmdline, in a batch double the `%`-signs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can do it (assuming you are talking about `Cases` folder in your desktop [in cmd]):

```bat
for /R "%userprofile%\Desktop\Cases" /D %A in (Reports.?) do @xcopy /s %~fA full_path_you_want
```

For batch file you should double the percent-signs (`%%`) just like this:

```bat
@echo off
for /R "%userprofile%\Desktop\Cases" /D %%A in (Reports.?) do xcopy /s %%~fA full_path_you_want
```

To learn more about commands and wildcards (`.?`) you can:

- Type `for /?` in a fresh cmd
- Check link https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_wildcards.php

Hope this helps!